# "Popular Artists" should be in the direct center of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I know its probably something I should know by now since I've been coding off and on for two years now, but I'm having a massive brain malfunction and the project is due tonight.

So yeah, I want the three items (All Images) "History", "Popular Artists", and "Sub-Genres" to fit nicely on the same line with popular artists being in the center.

[image: Screenshot of Webpage]

I've been working on it for hours and still have no clue.

Comment: We can't see how you're attempting to center elements with just a screenshot; include your code in your post.

Comment: please don't post images of your problem.  It is impossible for people to offer assistance from a picture.  You should instead include a [mcve] of your issue.